# Row-by-row comparison in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, comparison

I want to compare every row of a matrix with its every other row, element by element wise, using MATLAB. If two of the entries match, the result will be stored as 1, and if they don't match, it will be 0. This will give a symmetric matrix consisting of 0s and 1s.

For example, let A = [4 6 7 9 5; 2 6 9 9 1]

Then, the result expected is [1 1 1 1 1; 0 1 0 1 0; 0 1 0 1 0; 1 1 1 1 1]

The code I am using is (for a 1000*1000 random matrix):

```
    A = randi(50,1000,1000);
    B = zeros(1000000,1000);
    D = zeros(1000000,1);
    c=0;
        for i=1:1000
            for k=1:1000
                for j=1:1000
                    if A(i,j)==A(k,j)
                        B(k+c,j)=1;
                    else
                        B(k+c,j)=0;
                    end
                end
            end
            c=c+1000;
        end
        for l=1:1000000
            D(l)=0;
            for m=1:1000
                D(l)=D(l)+(B(l,m)/(1000));
            end
        end
        E=reshape(D,1000,1000);
```

This goes out of memory. Could anyone please suggest a solution or a more efficient code?

Comment: At which line does it go out of memory?

Comment: You do realize that if you want to check every possible combination of rows, your matrix will have `n^2` rows where `n` is the amount of rows in your matrix.  The amount of columns you have is 1000.... therefore, your final matrix is `1000000 x 1000`.  Also, each `double` is 8 bytes, so your total matrix size is 8 GB.... so obviously you are going to run out of memory.  Maybe you should convert your matrix into `logical`, but this will reduce your size down to 1 GB.  You need to decrease the size of your matrix if you want this code to work.

Comment: @rayryeng : You are right. But I cannot reduce the size of the matrix. Is there any other way in which the comparison can be made?

Comment: @AashayPatil - Maybe make your matrix `sparse`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html.  This will only work if your matrix has a lot of zeroes.  I don't know how your random matrix is distributed.  Try that and see if it works!

Comment: I would also go for a sparse matrix for the result, and only assign an element to `1` when a comparison is validated. Also, depending what are your input data, you could try to reduce the memory footprint by downgrading the data type (`single` or even integers if possible)

Answer (score 0):

you can try row by row comparison directly as taking a complete row array and comparing with the other row array.

For example, 
let

```
A = [4 6 7 9 5; 2 6 9 9 1];
nA = length(A(:,1));
finalMat = [];
for i = 1:nA
    matRow = ones(nA,1)*A(i,:); % create a matrix size of A consists of same row elements
    finalMat = [finalMat;matRow == A];
end
```

see if it is okay for you application.

Comment: provided the memory will be able to swallow it, you should preinitialise your `finalMat` ... otherwise Matlab is going to complain (and rightly so) that the array is growing at every iteration (=> runs slower).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) to align dimensions apprpriately and then [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) for the comparisons:

```
reshape(bsxfun(@eq, permute(A, [1 3 2]), permute(A, [3 1 2])), [], size(A,2))
```

Comment: Thanks! This is faster, but also goes out of memory for larger matrices.